# Why does Dexter use the same outfit for killing?

Tags: dexter

Dexter dresses in this outfit every time he commits a killing. Why does he use the same clothes? Is it some kind of signature?

[image]

Answer (score 23):

When you’ve got plans for the night, you better dress to kill. Literally. We’re not really sure why Dexter always wears the same long sleeve brown henley shirt. It could be because it helps him keep a low profile, it’s easier to keep track of which shirt might have traces of evidence on it or it could just be because he thinks it looks cool. Get the official Dexter Kill Uniform with Dexter embroidered on the sleeve.

The executive producer said in an interview that dexter buys them in bulk and throws them out each time, along with the bodies. they're army fatigues that he can buy in bulk, anonymously.

Comment: I think the second paragraph of your answer nicely answers the question. I would suggest moving it to the beginning of your answer.

Answer (score 10):

Also to add, his kills are very ritualistic. He repeats every thing in a fixed pattern. Setting up the kill room, the kill table, the weapons, drawing blood from the victim for the slides, etc. The uniform is part of his ritual too.